# Google App Engine: Determine whether Current Request is a Taskqueue

Tags: python, google-app-engine, task-queue

Is there a way to dynamically determine whether the currently executing task is a standard http request or a TaskQueue?

In some parts of my request handler, I make a few urlfetches. I would like the timeout delay of the url fetch to be short if the request is a standard http request and long if it is a TaskQueue.

Comment: Interesting. I suppose I would wrap the code that creates a TaskQueue request to add an additional boolean to kwargs. Could be messy.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pick any one of the following HTTP headers:

1. `X-AppEngine-QueueName`, the name of the queue (possibly default)
2. `X-AppEngine-TaskName`, the name of the task, or a system-generated unique ID if no name was specified
3. `X-AppEngine-TaskRetryCount`, the number of times this task has been retried; for the first attempt, this value is 0
4. `X-AppEngine-TaskETA`, the target execution time of the task, specified in microseconds since January 1st 1970.

Standard HTTP requests won't have these headers.

Answer (score 2):

Task requests always include a specific [set of HTTP headers](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/overview-push#task_request_headers), which you can check.

Comment: Same thing for the cron jobs.. `X-AppEngine-Cron: true` https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/cron#Securing_URLs_for_Cron